# How to create threads dynamically?

Tags: java, multithreading, dynamic

I want to create certain number of threads in my program where the number of threads to be created is provided by the user at run-time. Any suggestions ??

Comment: *"Any suggestions ??"*  Try writing some code.  Come back to us when you have a **specific** question.  Voting to close.

Comment: use classic concept LOOP

Comment: Well, you could call `new Thread().start()` n times. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.  A for loop is the easiest:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[numThreadsToCreate];
for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i] = new Thread(yourRunnable);
    threads[i].start();
}
```

Your `Runnable` could be something like this:

```
private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // your code to run in the thread goes here
    }
}
```

You could also use a thread-pool:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    threadPool.submit(yourRunnable);
}
// shutdown the pool once we submit the last job, they will continue to run
threadPool.shutdown();
```