# How To Create Dynamic Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to learn how to create a specified number of threads by the user in the console . There is not much to help me on and would like a detailed description on how to create a dynamic amount of threads. i know how to get the users input into a program using scanner but need help with the thread creation

i have tried to use this method as it makes the most amount of sense to me (i am a very amateur programmer studying CS):[How to create threads dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874587/how-to-create-threads-dynamically)

my code

package threads;

```
 public class morethreads {
   public Runnable MyRunnable;
       public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!" + i);
       }
    public void main(String args[]) {
    Thread[] hello = new Thread [10];//amount of threads
    for(int b =0; b < hello.length; b++){
        hello[b] = new Thread(MyRunnable);//<<this is the issue 
        hello[b].start();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Runnable` is an interface and by itself can't be instantiated, you need to have a concreate implementation which implements the requirements of the `interface`.  My guess is your code is generating a `NullPointerException` as `MyRunnable` is `null`. Start by having a look at [Concurrency in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and [Defining and Starting a Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) in particular

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run the run method in multiple threads. It is part of the morethreads class so this class needs to implement Runnable.

You then need to create an instance of it instead of Thread.

```
> public  class morethreads implements Runnable {
>     public void run() {
>         for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
>             System.out.println("Hello from a thread!" + i);
>     }
>     public static void main(String args[]) {
>         Thread[] hello = new Thread [10];//amount of threads
>         for(int b =0; b < hello.length; b++){
>             hello[b] = new Thread(new morethreads());
>             hello[b].start();
>         }
>     } }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: please show me how and where i have exactly gone wrong much apreciated

Comment: Thankyou very much not got a high enough rep to up this answer but definitely very helpful

Comment: Also it is good to keep to code style guidelines. You should start a class name with a capital and use camel case.   MoreThreads not morethreads.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following code:**

You need to implement the run method.

```
public class morethreads {
    public static Runnable MyRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) {
                System.out.println("Hello from a thread!" + i);
            }
        }
    };

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread[] hello = new Thread [10];//amount of threads
        for(int b =0; b < hello.length; b++) {
            hello[b] = new Thread(MyRunnable);//<<this is the issue 
            hello[b].start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: can you show me where or how i need to create an instance of thread please

Comment: In the above code, you have to initialize the MyRunnable object.  The important thing is the implementation of run method because Runnable is an interface.  Then, you can use the object (MyRunnable) as a parameter of Thread class.

Comment: In your code, you didnt intialize the MyRunnable object.

Comment: Thankyou  for the help i realized my mistake